# Is there a Lie group which is made $S^n \cup_f ~e^m$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is there a Lie group G which has only two cells?

i.e. $ G = S^n \cup_f~ e^m$ where $f:S^{m-1}\to S^n$ with $m>n$

How many exists that groups? Infinitely many?

If there is no Lie group which has only two cell, how many cells needed to a Lie group?

Comment: $U(1)$, with $m=1$, $n=0$. Can we have a bit of background to this question?

Comment: I want to non-sphere Lie group. Using confibration, I'll compute the homotopy set.

Comment: See Figures 3 and 4 of my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2131 for an answer to your last question for the exceptional Lie groups G_2 and F_4.

Answer (score 5):

Amongst compact Lie groups, the only examples are $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$, which topologically are $S^1$ and $S^3$.  All others are ruled out because their rational cohomology has dimension >3, except $SO(3,\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{RP}^3$, which has the same rational cohomology as $S^3$, but is ruled about because its mod 2 cohomology has dimension 4.

On the other hand, there are lots of unipotent Lie groups which are topologically the same as vector spaces.

Comment: rational cohomology dimension and number of cells are related?

Comment: @Jino: if the dimension of your cells are far apart, then computing (co)homology using the cellular complex shows there is a relation.

Comment: @Alvarez: Thank you. I missed that.

Comment: @Webster: Can you recommend a reference which contain your explanation dim > 3?

Comment: Mariano- The cells being far apart has nothing to do with it; the total dimension of cohomology over any field gives a lower bound on the number of cells you need.  Of course, sometimes it's too low because of cancellation; the rational cohomology of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ looks like it might allow you to get away with 2 cells, but the mod 2 cohomology shows you need 4.

Comment: I know, Ben; but when they are sufficiently apart (that is, not contiguous, in fact :) ) you do not get a bound but an actual count.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the same argument rules out H-spaces with three cells, by Hopf's Theorem which says that the rational cohomology ring is an exterior algebra on odd-dimensional generators. 

Comment: An even easier argument shows that any cell decomposition of a Lie group has to have an even number of cells, since it's Euler characteristic is zero (it's parallelisable, and in particular has a nowhere vanishing vector field). I'm not sure whether the argument can be adapted to H-spaces as well.